# How to setup Elixir properlty to use the new IEx breakpoints with Elixir 1.5?

Tags: elixir

I'm using Erlang 20 with Elixir 1.5.0, and I tried doing `break! URI.decode_query/2` in iex.  Then I received the following error:

```
** (RuntimeError) could not set breakpoint, module URI was not compiled with debug_info (iex) lib/iex.ex:647: IEx.break!/4
```

What option do I compile Erlang with and how do I do that? If it helps, I've been using [kerl](https://github.com/kerl/kerl) to build and manage my Erlang installs.

Comment: How did you install Elixir?

Comment: I used kiex https://github.com/taylor/kiex

Comment: My guess is kiex is using precompiled versions of elixir, this way iex can't set the breakpoint. You probably need to compile elixir yourself for it to work...

Answer (score 1):

Most version managers, including kerl, will install the precompiled versions of elixir which do not contain the required debug infos.

However, when downloading the source, compiling it via `make` and running the `iex` binary located in `/bin/`, you can successfully set breakpoints on those modules:

```
~/elixir_install/elixir-1.5.1/bin » ./iex
Erlang/OTP 20 [RELEASE CANDIDATE 2] [erts-9.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8 [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Interactive Elixir (1.5.1) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> break! URI.decode_query/2
1
iex(2)> URI.decode_query("percent=10", %{"starting" => "map"})
Break reached: URI.decode_query/2 (/home/johnny/elixir_install/elixir-1.5.1/lib/elixir/lib/uri.ex:136)

  134:   end
  135:
  136:   def decode_query(query, map) when is_binary(query) and is_map(map) do
  137:     decode_query_into_map(query, map)
  138:   end

pry(1)>
```

Comment: FWIW I have Elixir installed via Homebrew using a Homebrew "Bottle" (compiled binaries) and I am able to put a breakpoint on this function. Maybe kiex passes different flags when compiling Elixir than what Homebrew does to create their "Bottles".

Comment: Interesting, just had a look at the source of kiex, and it does indeed just call `make compile` like I did with the source.